# How to select a li with a specific class?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, dom-traversal

```
<ul id="attached_deals_tab" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Test1">Test1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#Test2">Test2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With a jquery like this, I could say get me all list items:

```
$('#attached_deals_tab li');
```

But how can I say show me only the `li` that has `class="active"` ? In one line please.

I know how to negate it:

```
$('#attached_deals_tab li:not(.active)');
```

But not the other way around...

Comment: This is a valid question, which I couldn't figure out. There is no reason to downvote this. It would be like saying nobody should ask questions and do tutorials instead.

Comment: In SO, newbies are welcome i believe, we shouldn't ideally down-vote because of inexperience of the person asking the question. Instead, we should promote learning.

Comment: @techfoobar We should promote learning, yes. That's what I'm doing. Newbies are very welcome, I have helped a lot of them, but they should show some effort. I don't think "How can I set something to bold in CSS?" type of questions are welcome.

Comment: Note: none of the answers care about the possibility that lists can be nested, the nested lists can have more `li`s that might have the class `active`. That can lead to surprises :).

Comment: @bažmegakapa Thats ridiculous. Where did I not show any effort? I have shown the combinations I have tried, which didn't succeed. You downvote a question that shows no code or nor any effort. If you don't want to help, just stay out of it and leave others help. No need for non-constructive down-votes. And again if you think none of the answers are so great, then answer properly instead of showing off in the comment section.

Comment: @Kave I expressed my opinion (a downvote is a way to do that), you expressed yours. I want to help, that's why I did what I did.

Comment: @Kave - As bažmegakapa pointed out, the answers dont take nesting into consideration. Use `#attached_deals_tab > li.active` for filtering immediate children only.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$('#attached_deals_tab li.active');
```

Comment: For more efficiency, you can also use $('#attached_deals_tab').find('li.active');

Answer (score 5):

This should do it, the syntax is just the same as in CSS:

```
$('#attached_deals_tab li.active');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the class once the `ul` id has been specified:

```
$("#attached_deals_tab .active");
```

Unless you have something other than `li`s in there and that something is also being applied the `active` class, which would be strange.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, do

```
$('#attached_deals_tab li.active').(...)
```

Comment: This has the potential to select more than just li elements

Comment: Okay, then I can make it `li.active`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the child selector to prepare your code for possible future nested lists:

```
$('#attached_deals_tab > .active')
```

It will select only direct children. According to the specification, an `ul` can only have `li` elements as its children, so when using the child selector, `.active` should suffice, no need to specify `li.active`.

By nested lists, I mean something like this:

```
<ul id="attached_deals_tab">
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Reading the [documentation on jQuery Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) will also help a lot.

Comment: Could the downvoter explain his reasons (other than being sooo hurt)? I am always happy to improve my answers.